# doesn't save custom java object in firebase in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(TeacherLogin.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            //getting current user and saving student info

            try {
                FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).push().setValue(teacherInfo);
                Toast.makeText(TeacherLogin.this, "succesfully signup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception is", e.toString());
            }
```

Comment: didn't add child to the database tree but show "successfully signup" ....Please help me

Comment: Show you TeacherInfo Class. Any exception do you see in logcat?

Comment: public class TeacherInfo {   private String name,department,phone,password,email;
    ArrayList<String> subjects;
    public TeacherInfo(){

    }

    public TeacherInfo(String name,  String department, String phone, String email,String password) {
        this.name = name;

        this.department = department;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.password=password;

    }

Comment: No exception in logcat

Comment: Does `Log.e("Exception is", e.toString());` print something in the logcat? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: no it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the child **subjects** in **TeacherInfo's** constructor like other entity.

```
    public TeacherInfo(String name, String department, String phone, String email, String password, ArrayList<String> subjects) { 
        this.name = name; 
        this.department = department; 
        this.phone = phone; 
        this.email = email; 
        this.password = password; 
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
```

Or you have to implement **Geter:Seter** for child entity.